# (Zabbix) edit template Item key from attached template

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, zabbix

I have custom template with attached template *PostgreSQL by Zabbix agent 2*. There is an Item with key *pgsql.custom.query*. But I can't edit item key in new custom template.

[Custom template image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zAgF.png)

[Item key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q104I.png)

How can I edit it (item key) only for custom template? Or how to add new custom query?

Thanks!